# Searching for specific phrase pattern within lines. python

Tags: python, regex, search, nlp, match-phrase

I have made certain rules that I need to search for in a file. These rules are essentially phrases with an unknown number of words within. For example,

`mutant...causes(...)GS`

Here, this a phrase, which I want to search for in my file. The `...` means a few words should be here(i.e. in this gap) & `(...)` means there may/may not  be words in this gap. `GS` here is a fixed string variable that I know.

Basically I made these rules by going through many such files and they tell me that a particular file does what I am looking for.

The problem is that the gap can have any(small) number of words. There can even be a new line that begins in one of the gaps. Hence, I cannot go for identical string matching.

Some example texts -

1. `!Series_summary "To better understand how the expression of a *mutant gene that causes ALS* can perturb the normal phenotype of astrocytes, and to identify genes that may`

Here the GS is ALS (defined) and the starred text should be found as a positive match for the rule `mutant...causes(...)GS`

2. `!Series_overall_design "The analysis includes 9 samples of genomic DNA from
   isolated splenic CD11c+ dendritic cells (>95% pure) per group. The two groups are neonates born to mothers with *induced allergy to ovalbumin*, and normal control neonates. All neonates are genetically and environmentally identical, and allergen-naive."`

Here the GS is ovalbumin (defined) and the starred text should be found as a positive match for the rule
`induced...to GS`

I am a beginner in programming in python, so any help will be great!!

Comment: `...` (gap) is actually **3 dots** or there are some **letters/words**. here.

Comment: @iNikkz no its not **3 dots**. there can be any number of words there

Comment: It would be nice to post an example text(s) for us to show our suggested solutions work. Right now, I can only suggest [`r"(?s)\bmutant\b\W+\w+.*?\bcauses\b.*?\bGS\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/hS5sL3/1)

Comment: @stribizhev I have added examples as you asked. Please have a look!

Comment: @stribizhev also, 'GS' here is not to be matched, its a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you started, it will read in your file and display all possible matching lines using a Python [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), this will help you to determine that it is matching all of the correct lines:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    data = f_input.read()
    print re.findall(r'(mutant\s.*?\scauses.*?GS)', data, re.S)
```

To then just search for just the presence of one match, change `findall` to `search`:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    data = f_input.read()
    if re.search(r'(mutant\s.*?\scauses.*?GS)', data, re.S):
        print 'found'
```

To carry this out on many such files, you could adapt it as follows:

```
import re
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*.*'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_input:
        data = f_input.read()
        if re.search(r'mutant\s.*?\scauses.*?GS', data, re.S):
            print "'{}' matches".format(filename)
```

Comment: I have two questions Martin. 1-what is the need for the overall curved brackets   and 2- what does the \s.*?\s  do?

Comment: The round brackets are not strictly necessary here as the whole expression is returned, they are used to specify which part of the search is to be returned. `\s` says look for one whitespace character, `.*?` means match any number of characters. Take a look at the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) documentation.

Comment: `re.M` is useless here since you are not using `^` or `$` in the pattern. `\s` requires a space to appear after `mutant`, what about punctuation?

Comment: True, I have removed it. As I said it was just to get the OP started, we really need to see more input samples before an exact expression can be suggested.

Comment: Right, I consider such answers to be more like comments. At least that is my understanding of a comment (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Hey Martin, I have added examples as you asked. Please have a look!

Comment: also Martin, 'GS' here is not to be matched, its a variable

Comment: Do you wish to match this variable one at time or is there are whole list you need to match at once?

Comment: the variable is to be matched one at a time